# Como preencher tabela com informações de um banco de dados?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabela-html

Então minha gente, antes de tudo, gostaria de dizer que sou iniciante e comecei a aprender essa semana então peguem leve comigo, por favor u.u

Então, eu to mexendo num site de teste aqui e tenho a seguinte situação: eu tenho três funcionários e cada um deles trabalhou uma certa quantidade de horas por dia. Essas informações estão todas em um bd.No script, o nome dos funcionários são identificados por: Obj[1][i].nome e as horas trabalhadas são identificadas por Obj[1][i].horas. O que eu quero fazer é somar todas as horas que cada funcionário trabalhou e mostra-las em sua respectiva coluna.

Bom, eu tentei fazer o seguinte:

Criei um array com os nomes dos funcionários para comparar com os nomes do banco de dados e se os nomes forem iguais, as horas serão somadas poréeeeeem, eu não sei como fazer pra isso aparecer na tabela. Eu não sei se o que eu fiz tá certo (provável que não) mas eu tentei a parte do código em que eu fiz isso tá aqui:

```
    if (Obj !== null) {

                    if (Obj[0].tipo === 1) {

                        var data = [];
                        nomes = new Array ("Alex", "Yamilla", "Fernanda");


                        jQuery("#status_projetos").html("");
                        jQuery("#resumo_alocacao").html("");


                        for(var x = 0; x < nomes.length; x++ )
                        {
                            soma = 0;



                        for (var i = 0; i < Obj[1].length; i++) {

                            var obj = {
                                label: Obj[1][i].nome_projeto,

                                data: Obj[1][i].horas
                            };
                            if(nome == Obj[l][i].nome)
                            {
                                soma+=horas;
                            }

                         }
```

ps: ignorem onde tá escrito  Obj[1][i].nome_projeto, isso é outra coisa. 
Se puderem ajudar beleza, se não, ok tbm :)

Comment: Bem Vinda ao StackOverflow, poderia adicionar o trecho do código HTML que mostra constroe essa tabela?

Answer (score 0):

Nao sei se é  isso que voce esta precisando mas acho je voce pode fazwer dessa maneira

```
$("ul").append('<li>'índice.array'</li>');
```